# SQL query - LIMIT output text from server

Tags: sql, limit

I have started building a notifications system.. And when a user posts on another users feed it sends the notification_text they've posted on the other users stream. I then output this text in the notifications. But I would like to LIMIT the amount of text in the SQL query it outputs, so if the user posts a long message it doesn't push the notification right down the page.

So lets say the user posts.

Hello, my name is Dave, and I'm a developer from Derby.

I would like it to only show a snippet of that output

Hello, my name is Dave, and I'm...

I've just never wrote anything like this so could someone possibly explain to me what I need to do.

```
<?php 
$call="SELECT * FROM notifications WHERE notification_targetuser =".$u2." ORDER BY notification_id DESC LIMIT 5";
$chant= mysqli_query($mysqli,$call);
$num = mysqli_num_rows($chant);
while($notification = mysqli_fetch_array($chant)){
$triggeredby_name = rawfeeds_user_core::getuser($notification['notification_triggeredby']);
$targetuser_name = rawfeeds_user_core::getuser($notification['notification_targetuser']);
                                                echo"<a href='profile.php?username=".$triggeredby_name['username']."'>";
echo "<img class='stream_profileimage' style='border:none;padding:0px;display:inline;' border=\"0\" src=\"imgs/cropped".$notification['notification_triggeredby'].".jpg\" 'this.src=\"img/no_profile_img.jpeg\"' width=\"40\" height=\"40\"></a>";
echo "<a href='".$notification['notification_throughurl']."'>";
echo $notification['notification_content'];
echo"<br/>";
echo $notification['notification_text'];
echo"<br/>";
echo $notification['notification_datetime'];
echo "</a><br/><br/><hr>";
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think there is anything in SQL syntax
Just use

```
LEFT(field name, LIMIT) AS shortText
```

Comment: Do I add that at the end of the query.

I thought I could do something like $n=$notification['notification_text'];

And then in the query LIMIT ".$n." WHERE ".$n."=30

Comment: SELECT Field1, Field2, LEFT(Notification_Text, LIMIT) AS shortText FROM notifications

Comment: I worked it out.. I just wasn't thinking. Got it working perfectly and posted my answer above. :D

Cheers for your help anyway Jack, I shall upvote your comments for your time.

Comment: Instead of substring fetched data just select limited data from field by calling above statement LEFT(notification_text, 40) AS notification_text

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was pretty simple.

I used

> $str=$notification['notification_text'];
>
> $text=substr($str, 0, 40);
>
> echo"$text";